# JavaScript password and password confirmation match

Tags: javascript

I am not able to match the passwords, before Submit is clicked.
The submit goes even if the passwords are different.

```js
var pass1 = document.getElementById('userPassword');
var pass2 = document.getElementById('userRepeatPassword');

function validatePassword(){
 if (pass2.value == pass1.value) {
  pass2.setCustomValidity('');
 } else {
  pass2.setCustomValidity('Both passwords do not match');
 }
}

pass1.addEventListener('change', validatePassword);
pass2.addEventListener('keyup', validatePassword);
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="login.php">
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="inputFirstName">First name:</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="inputFirstName" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="inputLastName">Last name:</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" id="inputLastName" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="inputEmail">Email address:</label>
 <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="inputEmail" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="inputPassword">Password:</label>
 <input type="password" class="form-control" name="userPassword" id="userPassword" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="inputRepeatPassword">Password repeat:</label>
 <input type="password" class="form-control" name="userRepeatPassword" id="userRepeatPassword" required>
</div>
<div class="form-actions">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="background-color: #c2c2c2; color: black; font-weight: bold;">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

It seems like I miss something, but I am not able to find it whole day already - any thoughts will be appreciated!

Comment: So, you want to *block* the submit if the passwords are different?  You'll have to add a clock event to the button (or a submit event to the form) to prevent the action if the passwords are different.

Comment: P.S. Make sure you check the passwords on the server side too, just in case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990378/javascript-form-validation-with-password-confirming

Comment: This won't fix your problem, but FYI, the `label for` and the id on your inputs don't match on the password fields

Comment: Yep I will check them on the server side as well, but I want to make sure the browser will not let people input different passwords

Comment: Seems to work fine in the snippet.

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/ook7nhk2/

Comment: I have tested it with both Chrome and IE and does not work - seems to work fine in the jsfiddle.net ... weird O_o

Comment: I had to load the script.js in the bottom of the body...

Comment: Next time open the browser's JavaScript console and look for error messages. It would have solved the problem immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The validate should return the validation status and the form's onsubmit event handler should be able to react. Here's the sample:

```js
var pass1 = document.getElementById('userPassword');
var pass2 = document.getElementById('userRepeatPassword');

function validatePassword() {
  var status = false;
  if (pass2.value == pass1.value) {
    status = true;
    pass2.setCustomValidity('');
  } else {
    pass2.setCustomValidity('Both passwords do not match');
  }
  return status;
}

pass1.addEventListener('change', validatePassword);
pass2.addEventListener('keyup', validatePassword);
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="login.php" onsubmit="return validatePassword();">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputFirstName">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" id="inputFirstName" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputLastName">Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" id="inputLastName" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail">Email address:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="inputEmail" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="userPassword" id="userPassword" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputRepeatPassword">Password repeat:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="userRepeatPassword" id="userRepeatPassword" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="background-color: #c2c2c2; color: black; font-weight: bold;">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Its working here https://s11.postimg.org/868lj76c3/working.png . Check your JS console for error.

Comment: `setCustomValidity` triggers the browser's built-in validation. There's no need to do it manually.

Comment: @Juhana I think that's what GeorgiTsvetanovTsenov is trying to do. Triggering built in validations with custom message.

Comment: Yes, I have triggered custom message with setCustomValidity(), but I had to load the script before the closing </body> tag in order to work

Comment: Or you can put this code inside $(document).ready event handler so that this code executes after page has loaded completely. Executing it in blocks above the form fails because the js code is trying to find the elements that are yet to initialise in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You have code to display if the passwords are the same or not. However, there is not any code to control how to handle submit with invalid passwords.

Here are two options:

1) `<form onSubmit>` as described in Pankaj's answer.

2) You could also have your validate function disable your submit button.

(Add an id to your submit `<button type="submit" id=submitBtn class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="background-color: #c2c2c2; color: black; font-weight: bold;">Submit</button>`

```
function validatePassword(){
    var submit = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
    if (pass2.value == pass1.value) {
        pass2.setCustomValidity('');
        submit.disabled = false;
    } else {
        pass2.setCustomValidity('Both passwords do not match');
        submit.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to disable the submit button, but raise the built in browser validation error when the passwords do not match

Answer (score 0):

The  had to be put in the bottom before the  in order to work.